# javascript Date() setHours with ToLocalString

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get date of a specific timezone and initialize hours, min and sec to midnight (00:00:00)?

i tried looking for a logic that will do what the code below does but the other way around and couldn't find one.of course this one wont work because i first set hours and only than convert to different timezone.

```
var dt = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
var new_dt = new Date(dt).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"})
```

any idea how can i get `"America/New_York"` time zone with hours,min,sec set to midnight?

Comment: it has reasons libs like this exist: https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 0):

var d = new Date("Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT-0500"); 
d.setFullYear(2017,05,30);